# Regular Expression date time using MVC Data Annotations

Tags: angularjs, regex, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm mixing MVC Data Annotations and AngularJs validations ng-pattern.
What I've done so far is this thing:

```
[RegularExpression("/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} 20|21|22|23|([0-1][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/", ErrorMessage = "Date format: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")]
```

As you can see, I try to format date: `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`.
I want to make it 24 hours time. 
My problem is that form is getting valid when I type:

- 2015-21 , 2015-22 // 2015-20 is not valid, cannot understand why
- 2015-12-20 21 // I want user to enter minutes and seconds, because it also has datetimepicker, which is more useful and it sets format as I want

So, why my regular expression is not working as I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex does not work as expected because you did not use a `^` anchor (although I guess this expression is anchored, but still it is better to play it safe) and you did not enclose the alternatives into a group, and thus `21`, `22`, `23` are valid values.

Here is a fixed expression:

```
^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} (?:20|21|22|23|(?:[0-1][0-9])):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$
                            ^^^                         ^^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rN1jN6/1)

Comment: actually yes, this works fine with AngularJs validations (javascript), but MVC seems to have different syntax or so. My ModelState.IsValid returns false on this date. I also use another regex for numbers, so that is fine. Maybe you know, what occurs this problem?

Comment: I do not know what the other regex look like but my suggested regex should work with any regex engine unless it does not support noncapturing groups. Which is not the cae I believe. What date do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

change your regex instead to be like this

```
^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} ((20|21|22|23)|([0-1][0-9])):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$
```

check this [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dN2tP4/1)

I only changed `20|21|22|23|([0-1][0-9])` in your regex to `((20|21|22|23)|([0-1][0-9]))`

Comment: thanks for your answer too, I was affraid to add parentesis, however I have now another problem, which I posted upper in comments, hope to find out the solution by myself ;D